# how to navigate the screen from app delegate to viewController in xcode 4.4

Tags: iphone, xcode4.4

I am using xcode 4.4 on os x 10.7,in any version if we give the navigation controller in the appdelegate the screen will navigate to the what ever the viewcontroller we have given.But in Xcode 4.4 its not navigating and its showing empty view controller.And in that view controller also i am not able to navigate to another view controller by using giving the action to the button.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: when we create a New Project with a MasterDetail template, what does it show at that time in xcode4.4 ? It should work as normal, try by creating a new..

Answer (score 0):

The app delegate never appears on the screen... It has the window property which refers to the screen. What i would suggest doing is initializing a view controller, then initialize a navigation controller and set the rootviewcontroller property of that to the view controller you created earlier. Then in the **applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method in the app delegate, do **[self.window setRootViewController:*nameOfYourNavigationController*];**